# combing mysql outer joins in a search

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables in my database

```
PROJECTS
- id
- name
- date_created
- user_created
- status (or for disabled, 1 for enabled)

PROJECTS_MANAGERS (a project may have 0 or more managers)
- id
- project_id
- manager_username

PROJECTS_MEMBERS (a project may have 0 or more members)
- id
- project_id
- member_username
```

I'm trying to create a mysql join query to list all the projects that a particular user is involved in where the status is equal to 1. Specifically, a query that will list ALL projects where username "bob" is in the "use_created", "manager_username", or "member_username" fields and where the projects.status field is 1. But the trick is there could be multiple managers or members with the same project_id (differsnt ids and member_usernames of course).

I've tried this code, but it doesn't seem to work (gives me the error '1054 unknown column 'projects.status' in where clause). I tried doing a "full join" but I've come to learn mysql does not support this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    `projects` as theProjects

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    projects_managers
            AS theManagers
                    ON theProjects.id = theManagers.project_id
WHERE
    projects.status = 1
UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM
    `projects` as theProjects
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    projects_members
            AS theMembers
                    ON theProjects.id = theMembers.project_id
        WHERE
    projects.status = 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of doing a UNION ALL, could you combine the two select statements into one and then add "(AND user_created = 'bob' OR manager_username = 'bob' OR member_username = 'bob')? Not sure this is what you're looking for...

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question, but might I suggest to change the database model (if possible) to use just one table for managers and members. They are both people which seem to work basically the same way (no pun intended ;-).

Comment: Well on certain screens, the database would need to query to see if the user logged in is a manager or a member, in allow certain functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT projects.*
FROM projects
LEFT JOIN projects_managers managers ON managers.project_id=projects.id
LEFT JOIN projects_members members ON members.project_id=projects.id
WHERE status=1 AND
      (user_created="bob" OR managers.username="bob" OR members.username="bob")
GROUP BY projects.id
```

Comment: How do I modify this query so that I can do the same thing, except where user_created != "Bob" and managers.username != "Bob" and members.username != "Bob".